# iperf3 error - unable to create a new stream: permission denied

Tags: iperf

I am new to using `iperf` but others in my company use it but today it is acting strangely.

From the server:
`iperf3 -s`
which results in `cmd` showing:
`Server listening on 5201`.

From the client:
`iperf3 --format k --length 1 -t 10 -b 1K -i 1 -c *myservername*`
which results in `cmd` showing on the client side:
`Connecting to host *myservername*, port 5201`
`iperft3: error - unable to create a new stream: Permission denied`
And `cmd` showing on the server side:
`Accepted connection from *myip*, port 20756`
`iperft3: error - unable to create a new stream: Permission denied`

I can't find any documentation on this so I'm even sure where to start. Can anyone point me in the right direction or anything I can test?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll leave the question here in case someone else runs into this problem.

Run as administrator on both ends. Easy peasy.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, using iperf from a network drive, and whereas i was running from a cmd as adminstrator i got the same error.
It seems that iperf need write permission on the share too.
moving program on C: run perfectly.

Comment: Good catch, it doesn't seem to work from CD-ROM/ISO either

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't need administrator rights, but it seems that iperf needs to be started from a writeable directory, although I didn't notice that it writes anything to the disk.

Running it from C:\Program Files\iperf-3.1.3-win64 (read only for a an ordinary user) results in the error

> iperf3: error - unable to create a new stream: Permission denied

Running it from RAM drive R:\iperf-3.1.3-win64 results in working application.